# In ajax method, return the whole php page,not the echo info

Tags: php, ajax

When I use ajax method to the data from server, I get the whole php page, not the echo info.Why?

JS:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);

myApp.config(function($httpProvider){
 $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(obj){
  var arrStr = [];
  for(var p in obj){
   arrStr.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+"="+encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
  }
  return arrStr.join("&");
 };
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 };
});

  

myApp.controller("content",["$scope","$http",function($scope,$http){
 var postData = {name:"Liu"};
 $scope.onClick = function(){
  $http.post("http://oda53d5ps.bkt.clouddn.com/post.php",postData)
   .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    $scope.result = data;
    console.log(data);
   });
 };
}]);
```

In my PHP files, it is " $str = $_POST["name"];  if($str == "Liu") {    echo "Success!";  } else {      echo "Failed!";   }"

Comment: Have you put "<?php" at the start of your PHP file? If not, add it as the server will not consider it PHP code unless this directive is there

Comment: I've add <?php ?> tag, but it sttill return the whoe php files.

Comment: Add <?php in the first line of the file and ?> at the end of the file, where your PHP code ends.

Comment: Yeah, i konw the php format.

Comment: I think the problem is that you server configuration is wrong, if you try to browse your post script http://oda53d5ps.bkt.clouddn.com/post.php its being automatically downloaded, that is due to a wrong server configuration

Comment: <?php
 $str = $_POST["name"];
 if($str == "Liu"){
  echo "Success";
 }
 else{
  echo "Failed";
 }
?>

Comment: You're using openresty, check out the docs about hosting php files and serve them

Comment: @lbs0912 After echo info add exit;